# SCSS file image @import commands not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am converting an old Rails 3.2 app to Rails 6.0.2.1

When trying to load a page I am getting a strange error.

```
File to import not found or unreadable: background.png.
Load paths:
  .../app/assets/config
  .../app/assets/images
  .../app/assets/stylesheets
```

but the file is in .../app/assets/images! The command in the scss file is

```
@import "background.png";
```

Does anyone has an idea of what might be causing this? Note that I am not at all familiar with css...

Comment: Could you provide your code example?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev, what code do you need?

Comment: `application.css` and view where you display image